# Can we handle ngxs @Action errors via ofActionErrored() without going to default "ErrorHandler"?

Tags: ngxs

I have an async ngxs action that `throwsError()`.

I would like the default error handling mechanism to ignore this thrown error because I will be handling it in my code via `ofActionErrored()`. However, for other actions, default error handling should still take place.

Right now, both the `ofActionErrored()` and default error handling (via Angular/Ionic) tries to deal with the error.

The alternative I can think of is to dispatch Xxx_SUCCESS and Xxx_ERROR actions from within the initially dispatched action, something I would like to avoid if i can help it.

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature request that raised a similar concern at the NGXS repo. We've discussed in the core team meeting and we'll focus that for the next release. You can provide your feedback there: https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1691

Answer (score 1):

You can use ofActionCompleted which as a result can provide the error, if there is one. An example taken from the code I am working on:

```
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofActionCompleted(GetMe)
).subscribe((data) => {
  const errorStatus = data.result.error['status'];

  if (!data.result.successful && errorStatus === 403) {
    this.snackbar.openFromComponent(TranslateSnakeBarComponent, {
      data: {message: 'USER_DISABLED'}
    });
  }
});
```